# Why 'if(!getimagesize($_FILES['imagefile']['tmp_name']))' doesn't work?

Tags: php

After the file is uploaded, why it always gives me the false even if it is image?

```
if (!getimagesize($_FILES['imagefile']['tmp_name'])) { $boolean = false; }
```

By the way, it gives me this error:
`Warning: getimagesize() [function.getimagesize]: Filename cannot be empty in...`

Comment: are you sure there is no upload error? also, could you give more code?

Comment: The warning definitely implies that no file labeled "imagefile" is making it to the server.

Comment: Yeah, so what to do? `$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]` isn't empty, it is so strange... I will shoot somebody I think soon...

Comment: in your question: `$_FILES['imagefile']['tmp_name']` in your comment: `$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]`. i would do a print_r($_FILES); and see what it says.

Comment: Jayrox, you should have posted this in the answers, because it helped me the most, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your file is being uploaded before carrying any operation on it. Just dump the `$_FILES` array while development, like:

```
echo '<pre>'; print_r($_FILES);echo '</pre>';
```

You need to have a `enctype` attribute applied on your `<form>`  tag, for uploading a file. See http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.3

Comment: I have added `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. The `[tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\phpA3D5.tmp`, but I guess it's bad path? But still, if I don't add that if clause, then it uploads image perfectly. Omg :/

Comment: @hey: Yes, it could be difference in upload settings between your local server and online one.

Answer (score 1):

First check if the upload is actually succeeding:

```
if ($_FILES['imagefile']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
   if (!getimagesize(....)) {
      ... 
   }
} else {
   die("Upload failed with error code {$_FILES['imagefile']['error']}");
}
```

The error constants are [defined here](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php). Never assume an upload succeeded. There's only one way for them to work, and a million ways for them to fail.

Given that `getimagesize()` is complaining about an empty file name, either:

a. the upload failed, the reason code for which will be in the `...['error']` attribute.

b. you're checking the wrong file field name. If you've got `<input type="file" name="image" />` then you have to check `$_FILES['image'][...]`.

c. for whatever reason, your web server is able to WRITE files to the temporary directory, but does not have READ permissions.